# how to use a ContextBoundObject to intercept a function call before/after the invocation?

Tags: c#, .net, aop

I have read [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/1111302072009051446AM/11113.aspx) and I can't find a good example for how to use a `ContextBoundObject` to intercept a function call.
Can anyone show me how it's done?

Also, a side question: Why can't I use a `ContextBoundObject` with a generic class? I am asking accroding to [this msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.contextboundobject.aspx)

Comment: I have found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/aopsimplestscenario.aspx) that explains everything.